# Maximum entropy prior for r.v. supported on real line with no other constraints?

Tags: prior, maximum-entropy, uninformative-prior

What would be a suitable maximum entropy prior for a random variable supported on the real line with no other constraints (i.e. unknown mean, unknown variance, unknown bounds)?

All kinds of answers (mathematical, philosophical...) appreciated.